# How can I use SUMIF to extract dates only newer than 7 days, 14 days etc.?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I work in a production environment where we want to keep a simple log of issues that may prop up with our machinery during production, the two columns relevant for this issue;

| Date | Hours until resolution |
| --- | --- |

I want to keep separate sheets for each machine and then display the downtime for each machine for the previous 7, 14, 21 etc. days.
To sum the amount of downtime hours from X days ago until now I'm trying do use this formula;

```
=SUMIF('Machine A'!A2:A99; ">TODAY()-7"; 'Machine A'!E2:E99)
```

and I can not for the life of me figure out why the criteria isn't giving me what I want.
I've used the examples from [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumif-function) to try and find an alternative solution which doesn't work either, the formula either sums ALL numbers within the range or NONE of them.

Answer (score 1):

As explained on the link from the OP, you must concatenate an operator to the date. Change your criteria like below:

```
=SUMIF('Machine A'!A2:A99; ">" & TODAY()-7; 'Machine A'!E2:E99)
```

Comment: Also worth pointing out that the TODAY() function makes all of these volatile, so they get calculated every time anything changes, anywhere. Probably better to put =TODAY() in a cell somewhere, give it the name "DateToday" and refer to that as ">"&DateToday-7 for example

Answer (score 0):

As the Answer given says.

Not addressed exactly though was the literal source of your formula's failure.

By including the `TODAY()` function and the subtraction of 7 from it INSIDE the double quote marks, you made it just letters and numbers. It was part of the string, and not ever considered by Excel as the function and subtraction you desired.

By putting ONLY the `>` operator in the quotes, `Reddy Lutonadio` created a string from the operator and the result of the now-regarded-as-a-function-and-subtraction of `Today()-7`.

Always have to watch out for where those double quotes go!